# What does mean by this allowance sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118715/synopsis)

> Maude gives him an allowance but his weakness is vanity; "Hence the
>   slut"

What does mean by this above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The synopsis mentions

> Maude retorts that her father actually has no money; it was all her mother's or else belongs to the Foundation

So her father has no money. She is a source of money for him.

> [allowance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allowance)
>   b :  a sum granted as a reimbursement or bounty or for expenses
>   <*salary includes cost-of-living allowance*>;
>   **especially** :  a sum regularly provided for personal or household expenses
>   <*each child has an allowance*>

In other words, Maude gives him some money regularly (for example, monthly) for his personal expenses.

Comment: thank you max, but she also mention the word slut, so what does it mean ?

Comment: You didn't specifically ask about that. I can't remember how the movie goes, but I assume that the father has a mistress. Actually, if I remember correctly he was involved with a very young girl, possibly underage. Maude is referring to the girl when she says "Hence the slut". "Hence" because he wants to show off; this is what she means by "vanity".